# Highcharts & Joomla debug

Tags: highcharts

I've been playing around with highcharts for the first time because it looks amazing! I'm trying to implement it on the Joomla platform but don't seem to be able to get it working.

I think I've successfully called the highcharts.js and jquery in the head. And I've added the div with the sample code down the page but the chart does not seem to be drawing. If I look at the console in firebug I can see there is a syntax error but unfortunantly I can't see what might be causing it given that I just cut and paste the sample code.

Thanks in advance,
Rowan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah fixed it myself, I googled the error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL and it turns out sometimes when you copy and paste js it does some weird things at the end. So I deleted the last line and simple retyped it and hey presto!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with jquery / mootols problem, have you tried to use highcharts mootos wrapper without jquery or use noConflict `jQuery.noConflict();` ?

Comment: HI Sebastian, thanks for your suggestion. I tried a few variations of those approaches but none seem to have made a difference. I just tried disabling mootools from the site (which caused a few other errors) but this did not resolve the original error "SyntaxError: illegal character });​ " and points to the very end of the chart js.

Comment: I'm not seeing chart configruation now, but if you have problem with bracket, you can use jslint to check where the problem is.